# Why is Scotch-Yoke mechanism not used for internal combustion reciprocating piston engines?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, engines, linkage

Regarding piston acceleration variations due to the geometric nature of crankshaft and connecting rod motion, in relation to connecting rod length and bore to stroke ratio.

Why is [Scotch-Yoke mechanism](https://2.bp.blogspot.com/-wKbBBNQvwJU/T5_XKRt9BBI/AAAAAAAALr0/Erakyh7Ymk4/s400/Scotch+yoke.gif) not a viable choice for reciprocating to rotary motion conversion, applied to internal combustion piston engines? (whatever the purpose and scale of this engine)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Making an engine using scotch-yoke mechanisms for all pistons on a multi-cylinder engine will increase the cost and add a lot of needless complexity and mass, especially rotating mass that won't improve the output very much.

Then also consider that there are increased friction losses as well.

We did a laboratory experiment where we measured the angular velocities of the piston comparing scotch-yoke to the classic crank & con rod. Plotting the relative velocities etc Probably still have the writ-up somewhere but it's in the attic...

The piston still has the same time from TDC to BDC etc as that is based on the crankshaft rotation.

Comment: This answer has been flagged as being "low-quality because of its length and content". As one who has been accused of having written pithy memos, which bean counters & those with arts & law degrees have difficulty with because brevity, this answer is very pithy. As it currently stands, this is more like a comment. To appease the person who flagged this, could you please pad out your answer with some verbiage.

Comment: @Fred let's hope the flagger is appeased and now gives a vote.

Comment: Most excellently "fluffed up" with padding. ;-) You have vindicated my decision to not delete your answer & also scored an additional up vote.

Comment: @SolarMike the question is mostly from mid-stroke point to next mid-stroke point, where acceleration of the piston is asymmetric in case of crank and rod.

Comment: I may rather have asked "what are the benefits of having greater piston acceleration near TDC than near BDC in internal combustion engines using crank and connection rod?"

Comment: @qqjkztd if you know what you want to ask, then that will be a start. We used a DSO to get the piston position from 2 mechanical rig setups  etc to plot and compare. What are you using?